# PostgreSQL "Illegal Group Name"

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, chown

I am trying to create a PostgreSQL database using this tutorial:
http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/environment/environment.html

The Postgres section can be found 2/3 of the way down the page.
After installing Homebrew and commanding `brew install postgresql`

we create a database by:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/pgsql/data
sudo chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
sudo su postgres
initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
createuser `whoami`
```

When I do `sudo chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data`

it returns the error

```
chown: postgres: illegal group name
```

Which is because, as I understand, I haven't created a user or group. Is there a simple, one-line command I can do to amend this, without going through an entirely different tutorial? Did this tutorial forget something?

Answer (score 2):

According to - http://russbrooks.com/2010/11/25/install-postgresql-9-on-os-x

"The Homebrew formula does not create a "postgres" user, as was common up to this point. Out of the box, you authenticate against the DB using the same user account under which you ran brew install. It's perfectly acceptable to leave it that way on your Dev machine. Don't forget to change that if this is a Production environment."

You can just skip to the next step: `initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data`

Answer (score 0):

this is a unix question.  there is a file called /etc/group which contains all of the groups in the system.  when you created the unix user postgres, you should have created the group postgres at the same time, and made the postgres user belong to the postgres group.  That relationship is in the /etc/passwd file.  So, if you look in the /etc/passwd file:

```
grep postgres /etc/passwd
```

you should see something like:

```
postgres:x:109:119:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
```

the 109 in my case is the postgres user id.  the 119 is the postgres group id, which I can see using this command:

```
grep postgres /etc/group
```

in my case, I see:

```
postgres:x:119:
```

I looked at the tutorial, brew install postgresql, for whatever reason, it creates the postgres user and not the postgres group.  Creating the group is simply adding a line in the /etc/group file called postgres with a UNIQUE number not already used by another group. Often there is a unix utility, depending on flavor of unix, like:

```
addgroup postgres
```

which will create the group for you.  If not, simply add the line to file with your favorite editor.

Your /etc/passwd file will have a group reference (the second number, as described above mine was 119).  If you take that number that you have you can look in the /etc/group file to see which group has been assigned to your postgres user.  Doesn't matter though, edit the /etc/passwd file (many unix flavors have vipw which helps edit the file) and go to the line with postgres on it and change the group number to the newly created group number.  Save it, then continue on your tutorial.

By the way, if the user wasn't created either, you can create the user and the group with the command:

```
adduser postgres
```

to delete the postgres user entirely, and start over again, you could:

```
deluser postgres
adduser postgres
```

Again, these commands are examples and don't work for all flavors of unix.  My examples are for linux (ubuntu 12 specifically). Be careful.  Good luck.

-g

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I’ve got the group created, but not it’s returning `illegal user name`. `adduser` returns `command not found`, but perhaps it is `createuser`? [link] (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createuser.html)
This returns `ERROR: role “juliushamilton” already exists.`
Should I create a new user name…?

Comment: *but now it's returning ^

Comment: no, it's not createuser.  that is a postgres command.  you are having issues with unix users and groups.  those are not postgres users and groups (roles).

Answer (score 0):

On mac OS, I executed:

```
mkdir /Users/alejandro/opt/postgresql14/my_project_ts
sudo chown -R PostgreSQL /Users/alejandro/opt/postgresql14/my_project_ts
```

[image]